# Skip Maui Blazor legacy dependencies for specific Platforms

Tags: blazor, maui

I need to use `Ghostscript` to extract a thumbnail from uploaded pdf documents on my Maui Blazor app.
Unfortunately, `Ghostscript` renders page images as Microsoft `System.Drawing.Image` so I need to reference `System.Drawing.Common` for .Net Core 3, which is not supported by Android or IOS platforms
I can decorate functions with `SupportedOSPlatformAttribute`.
I also can test if `DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.WinUI`
But deploying to IOS or Android complains about Microsoft System.Drawing.Common dependency.
Is there any way to skip this dependency for specific platforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your .csproj file. Use a "Conditional" to include dependencies only on certain platform(s):

```xml
<ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('net6.0-windows'))" >
   ...windows only dependencies here...
</ItemGroup>
```